# Cypher: How to create a recursive cost query with alternates?

Tags: cypher

I have the following structure:

`(:pattern)-[:contains]->(:pattern)`
...basically a hierarchy of patterns that use other patterns as content. These constitute trees.

Certain patterns are generated by certain generators:

```
(:generator)-[:canProduce]->(:pattern)
```

The `canProduce` relationship has a cost value associated with it as a property. Multiple generators can create the same pattern.

I would like to figure out, with a query, what patterns I need to generate to produce a particular output - and which generators to choose to have the lowest cost. I started like this:

```
MATCH (p:pattern {name: 'preciousPattern'})-[:contains *]->(ps:pattern) RETURN ps
```

so far so good. The results don't contain the starting pattern, so I made this:

```
MATCH (p:pattern {name: 'preciousPattern'})-[:contains *]->(ps:pattern)
WITH p+collect(ps) as list
UNWIND list as patterns
RETURN patterns
```

That does not feel elegant, but it also does not provide the hierarchy
I can of course do a path query (`MATCH path = MATCH...`) but the results don't seem very useful.

Also, now I need to connect the cost from the generator relationship.

I tried this:

```
MATCH (p:pattern {name: 'awesome'})-[:contains *]->(ps:pattern)
WITH p+collect(ps) as list
UNWIND list as rec
CALL {
WITH rec
MATCH (rec)-[r:canGenerate]-(g:generator)
return r.GenCost as GenCost, g.name AS GenName
}
return rec.name, GenCost , GenName
```

The problem I have now is that if any of the patterns that are part of another pattern can be generated by multiple generators, I just get double entries in the list, but what I want is separate lists for each alternative possibility, so that I can generate the cost.

This is my pattern tree:

- Awesome

  - input1
  - input2

    - input 3

Input 3 can be generated by 2 different generators. I now get:

```
Awesome   |  2    | MainGen
input1    |  3    | TestGen1
input2    |  2.5  | TestGen2
input3    |  1.25 | TestGen3
input4    |  1.4  | TestGen4
```

What I want is this: Two lists (or n, in the general case, where I might have n possible paths), one

```
Awesome   |  2    | MainGen
input1    |  3    | TestGen1
input2    |  2.5  | TestGen2
input3    |  1.25 | TestGen3
```

and one:

```
Awesome   |  2    | MainGen
input1    |  3    | TestGen1
input2    |  2.5  | TestGen2
input4    |  1.4  | TestGen4
```

each set representing one alternative set, so that I can calculate the costs and compare.

I have no idea how to do something like that. Any suggestions?